# object helper methods using react-moralis

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

How do I log out of a wallet using Moralis?

This allowed me to log in:

```html
<button className="button-connect" 
    onClick={() => enableWeb3({provider: 'Current Provider'})} 
    disabled={isWeb3EnableLoading}>
    Connect Wallet
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useMoralis` hook seems to be coming with the logout function:

```
const LogoutButton = () => {
  const { logout, isAuthenticating } = useMoralis();

  <button onClick={() => logout()} disabled={isAuthenticating}>
    Authenticate
  </button>;
};
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moralis#logout